# Driver not found when class is instanced dynamically

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7

When dynamically instantiate a class that uses a sql server driver get an error `(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver).`

To create the class dynamically i use the form `Class.forName ("MyClass")`, and in the constructor of the `class ("MyClass")` again use the form `Class.forName` `("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");` to get the driver instance.

Someone could help me with this problem?? Thank you ...

Comment: Either the class is missing from your classpath or it had a problem initialising, should show up first time you try to load it, after that all you will see is class not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add sqljdbc.jar or sqljdbc4.jar (as depends) in the classpath.
2. I believe the correct class name is: **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**